# Find correct corresponding point to extend line

Tags: geometry

I tried this at stackoverflow but was told it's more of a geometry problem than programming. So here goes.

I have two non parallel lines(XA and YB) which I need to extend to a curved line piece(PQ). The lines are made of arrays of (x,y) points. A is the last point in XA line and B is the last point in YB line. P and Q are the edge points of the curve.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now, I need to extend point A to P and point B to Q. Is there a way I can find the correct corresponding point of PQ curve so that A->P and B->Q and not A->Q and B->P, in the latter case the extended lines would intersect, that shouldn't happen.

Previously I had tried a simple boolean, but it was incorrect.

What I tried;

```
if(abs(A.x() - P.x()) < abs(B.x() - P.x())
   // extend A to P
   // extend B to Q
else
   // extend A to Q
   // extend B to P
```

The above wouldn't work for the image shown below, as then line A would be extended to point Q and line B to P (extension drawn in red).

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try using the y-coordinate instead of the x-coordinate?

Comment: That woudn't work either. The Y can vary as well. I think the best solution would be to find if the AP and BQ intesect.. but I'm not sure on how to check that..

Comment: Does my answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(A.y() > B.x())
   if(P.y() > Q.y())
         // extend A to P
         // extend B to Q
   else
         // extend A to Q
         // extend B to P
else
   if(P.y() > Q.y())
         // extend A to Q
         // extend B to P
   else
         // extend A to P
         // extend B to Q
```